# Remove leading zeroes in decimals when the variable has been created from a string

Tags: r

I have a string variable x <- c("1", "2", "3.14", "4.235"). I need to convert it to numeric format of the form x(1, 2, 3.14, 4.235). I have used the functions - as.numeric(), as.integer() and as.double() but without success. Need help here please!

Comment: You can't store numeric and integer in a single vector.  It can be either of class numeric or integer.

Comment: If you indeed have a character vector `as.numeric` works. Period. If it doesn't work (what exactly does that mean?) you don't have a character vector. Since we can't know what you have there is nothing we can do for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But as i said the form must be (1, 2, 3.14, 4.235). The function as.numeric makes it (1.000, 2.000, 3.140, 4.235). I admit that the requirement may be a bit weird. But it is what it is. I wanted the decimals to disappear if any number in the vector was an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it not working try the following

```
x <- c("1", "2", "3.14", "4.235")
x <- as.numeric(x)
class(x)
[1] "numeric"
```